Телеграм бот на с++ отказался работать

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tgbot/tgbot.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    TgBot::Bot bot("");
    bot.getEvents().onCommand("start", [&bot](TgBot::Message::Ptr message) {
        bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "Hi!");
    });
    bot.getEvents().onAnyMessage([&bot](TgBot::Message::Ptr message) {
        printf("User wrote %s\n", message->text.c_str());
        if (StringTools::startsWith(message->text, "/start")) {
            return;
        }
        bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "Your message is: " + message->text);
    });
    try {
        printf("Bot username: %s\n", bot.getApi().getMe()->username.c_str());
        TgBot::TgLongPoll longPoll(bot);
        while (true) {
            printf("Long poll started\n");
            longPoll.start();
        }
    } catch (TgBot::TgException& e) {
        printf("error: %s\n", e.what());
    }
    return 0;
}

Зашел сюда https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp
Все сделал но не чего не работает. Токен написан. Помогите пожалуйста

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Пожалуйста, вставьте код кодом, а не картинкой. Его даже у себя не проверить. В вопросе есть кнопка "править". Уточните, что именно не работает. Почитайте справку. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
